# vue-cli eslint not catching errors

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli

I am trying to get my eslint setup for my new vue cli project. It doesn't work. It passes but I doesn't catch the errors I am intentionally adding. Any ideas what I did wrong?

vue.config.js

```
  devServer: {
    overlay: {
      warnings: true,
      errors: true,
    },
  },
  lintOnSave: true,
```

.eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    browser: true,
    node: true,
  },
  parserOptions: {
    parser: "babel-eslint",
  },
  extends: ["plugin:vue/essential", "eslint:recommended", "@vue/prettier"],
  plugins: ["prettier"],
  // add your custom rules here
  rules: {
    semi: "error",
    "no-console": process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "error" : "off",
    "no-debugger": process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "error" : "off",
  },
};
```

src/App.vue:

```
...
methods: {
  test() {
    return true;
  },
},
...
```

vue-cli-service lint results:

```
> project@0.1.0 lint /project/location/component_library
> vue-cli-service lint

 DONE  No lint errors found!
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's vue-cli project and if you're using vue-cli-ui, go to 'Plugins' => 'Add Plugin' and search & install `eslint-plugin-vue` on vue-cli plugins page. It's much simplified for easy use, manages linting with correct options. On the post installation screen, select eslint-type (prettier, airbnb etc)
(or)
you can set your parser to `vue-eslint-parser` and parser options to `babel-eslint`

or if you're not using vue-cli service this is a minimal set of configurations using `eslint-plugin-vue`, add it to .eslintrc.js file.

```
module.exports = { 
  root: true,
  env: {
    browser: true,
    node: true
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:vue/strongly-recommended',
    'plugin:vue/essential',
    '@vue/prettier', //recommended use @vue/airbnb

  ],
  // add your custom rules here
  rules: {
    //"semi": "error",
    //"no-console": process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "error" : "off",
    //"no-debugger": process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "error" : "off",
    //"no-unused-vars": process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "error" : "off",
    //"vue/no-side-effects-in-computed-properties": "off",
    //"vue/no-async-in-computed-properties": "off",
   
  }, 
  parser: "vue-eslint-parser",
  parserOptions: {
    parser: "babel-eslint",
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  plugins: [
    //plugins list
  ],
}
```